# getServerSideProps nextjs app router alternative

Tags: typescript, next.js

Suppose I have a dynamic route in my application, lets call it [id]

Usually what I do in pages router is that I use `getServerSideProps` to validate eventual properties passed to the route. This could look something like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) {

    const { locale, query } = ctx

    //Validate query id
    const id = parseInt(query.id as string, 10)
    
    if(isNaN(id)) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        }
    }
    else {
        //Do some logic here, to either validate the id against the api or just forward it to the client as props
    }
}
```

I like this approach, cause it gives me nice separation, unfortunately this doesn't seem like a valid approach with `app router`.

This might be a question of preference, but how can I achieve something similar with the app router? The documentation is not quite clear to me.

Comment: So you want to implement the above code with respect to app router ? This part confused me `but how can I achieve something similar with the pages router? `

Comment: Oops, my bad - i just edited my post

Answer (score 1):

In the app router your "pages" are server components which can be asynchronous. Implementing the logic you have there could look something like this:

```
import { notFound } from "next/navigation";

interface Props {
  searchParams: { id?: string, locale?: string },
}

export default async function Page(props: Props): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  const { id, locale } = props.searchParams;

  // calling "notFound()" does not need a return statement
  if (isNaN(parseInt(id as string, 10))) notFound();

  // added a pseudo network request for clarity
  const response = await fetch(`https://example.com/users/${id}`);
  const json = await response.json();

  return (
    <pre>
      <code>{json}</code>
    </pre>
  );
}
```

As you can see this approach does not necessarily require you to have a separate function but you can always define the networking and validation logic in a separate function above or below your component.